# Rspec controller test hanging

Tags: testing, rspec, controller

Here is my controller test ("spec/controllers/api/tasks_controller_spec.rb")

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Api::TasksController do
    before :each do
        @quadros = create :cat
        @task = Task.new(:content => "Example task for #api")
        @quadros.add_task(@task)
    end

    describe "GET index" do
        it "returns a list of all user's tasks" do
            get :index, :format => 'json'
            expect(response).to eq(User.first.all_tasks)
        end 
    end
end
```

Here is my Api::BaseController

```
class Api::BaseController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :json
    skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!
end
```

And Api::TasksController

```
class Api::TasksController < Api::BaseController
    def index
        @tasks = User.first.all_tasks
        respond_with @tasks.to_json
    end
end
```

My other test run fine.

When I run the api test, it executes the before block, makes the request as json, and then hangs on this query:

```
Processing by Api::TasksController#index as JSON
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` LIMIT 1
  Tag Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` WHERE (user_id = 418 AND parent_tag_id IS NOT NULL)
  Tag Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` WHERE `tags`.`id` IN (NULL)
  Tag Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` WHERE (user_id = 418 AND parent_tag_id IS NULL)
  Task Load (0.7ms)  SELECT tasks.* FROM `tasks` JOIN tag_tasks on tasks.id = tag_tasks.task_id WHERE (tag_tasks.tag_id IN (301) OR creator_id = 418) GROUP BY tasks.id ORDER BY tasks.created_at DESC
Completed 200 OK in 99ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` LIMIT 1
  Tag Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` WHERE (user_id = 418 AND parent_tag_id IS NOT NULL)
  Tag Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` WHERE `tags`.`id` IN (NULL)
  Tag Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` WHERE (user_id = 418 AND parent_tag_id IS NULL)
  Task Load (0.7ms)  SELECT tasks.* FROM `tasks` JOIN tag_tasks on tasks.id = tag_tasks.task_id WHERE (tag_tasks.tag_id IN (301) OR creator_id = 418) GROUP BY tasks.id ORDER BY tasks.created_at DESC
```

Where it will just sit forever.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

I've come across a similar issue, and it appears the problem is with your expectation line:

```
expect(response).to eq(User.first.all_tasks)
```

This is not how RSpec wants you to test the response body. Notice that [in the docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs), specialized matchers are used instead of the equality matcher:

```
expect(response).to render_template("index")
```

So the `response` object, which is an `ActionController::TestResponse`, is meant to be queried about *what happened*, not what the response body was. So your test should be something like:

```
expect(JSON.parse(response.body)).to eq(User.first.all_tasks)
```

(Note that the response body is a string.)

As for the explanation of why the test hangs—instead of outright failing—it appears that this block of code (`lib/rspec/expectations/fail_with.rb:22` in the `rspec-expectations` gem version 2.14.0) is the culprit:

```
if actual && expected
  if all_strings?(actual, expected)
    if any_multiline_strings?(actual, expected)
      message << "\nDiff:" << differ.diff_as_string(coerce_to_string(actual), coerce_to_string(expected))
    end
  elsif no_procs?(actual, expected) && no_numbers?(actual, expected)
    message << "\nDiff:" << differ.diff_as_object(actual, expected)
  end
end
```

The `all_strings?`, `any_multiline_strings?`, `no_procs?`, and `no_numbers?` methods (defined in the same file) all invoke `args.flatten` on `[actual, expected]`. In this case, from what I can tell the problem is that `actual` is a `TestResponse`, which causes the `flatten` method itself to hang without raising a runtime error. I didn't have time to investigate this further, but the source for `Array.flatten` is [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/715d5d93b32d7fc011082fc0db5433904fec298f/array.c#L4301) if anyone is interested.